# unable to run bash script from bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, raspberry-pi

I've created a script that has to be executed on boot and has to run another script (which sets some variables) before executing other commands.

After writing the script, I've successfully executed it in the console, but if the script is added to crontab, the other script inside this one is not executed.

The script (main-script.sh) that has been added to crontab is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/pi/test-script.sh
python mycustompythonscript.py
```

and the test-script.sh is the following (I replaced the actual script with this one for testing):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "greetings from test script" > test.txt
```

So when i run main-script.sh from console, test-script.sh is executed (the file is created) and the python script is executed. Upon rebooting the RPi, however, the python script is executed, but the test-script.sh is not executed (test.txt file is not created).

Does anyone know what could be the possible reason that test-script.sh is not executed in case the main-script.sh is executed by cron?

Comment: Depending on how you're executing `main-script.sh` in crontab, it might be executed via `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.  In case of `source` command it's bash-specific. Try to replace that with `. /home/pi/test-script.sh`  - that should work across the board on all POSIX compliant, bourne-like shells. Let me know if that works for you, and if it does I'll post it as a proper answer

Comment: You can set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your crontab which makes life easier.

Comment: I don't know how it finds the python script: You don't give an absolute path.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy The script has a hash-bash-slash-bin-slash-bash `#!/bin/bash`, so a modern `sh` will launch `bash`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  As I mentioned in the comment, "Depending on how you're executing main-script.sh". A `sh /path/to/main.sh` definitely won't like bashisms (unless it's CentOS where `/bin/sh` is `/bin/bash` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an absolute path for `test.txt`. It won't put it where you expect.

do `sudo find / -iname "test.txt"` to find it.

(The python script should also have a full path name.)

Comment: python seems to be in `/usr/bin`, so it's found.

Comment: @Freddy Python script, not python interpreter.

Comment: Oops, you're right!